# Can I refresh/update datasource (dataset) in wpf application after changes on database?

Tags: c#, wpf, dataset, connection-string, datasource

I´ve already connected a data source to my wpf application and been working on it for some time.
I realized that I have to add column to my database.
Is there any way to refresh / update the datasource so the changes I´ve done to my database are reflected into my data source in Visual Studio ?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: No. I´m using dataset. Add new data source -> Database -> Dataset and using .sdf databse

Answer (score 0):

I use dataset.AcceptChanges() to resolve it.

Comment: Absolutly not, AcceptChanges() only set the boolean property hasChanges 
 of the dataset to false, making the update doing nothing